# Are there pitfalls to using output buffering in functions that shouldn't have output?

Tags: php

Sometimes we have functions which aren't intended to print (ie. output) anything. However, if some code within them throws an error, this will sometimes be output. That'll mean that this error shows up in our final HTML at whatever point the function was run. To avoid this, it occurs to me that it might be a good idea to put `ob_start();` at the start of the function, and `ob_end();` at the end (or before the `return` statement).

Is this a bad idea? Is it good practice? Are there pitfalls? Should I use `ob_end_clean()` instead?

How nested output buffering works seems relevant, but I don't understand this. It just occurs to me that my function might be called when another function has run `ob_start();` but not yet run `ob_end();`.

An example might be in WordPress or Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly pitfalls. As you stated yourself the whole thing breaks down once an unexpected exception is thrown and not caught. Same goes for fatal errors that may occur. Output buffering should only be used where you want to ... well ... buffer the output.

Whether or not an error is shown or not should be totally independent of that and you should properly set your [`error_reporting()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) for that (i.e. don't display anything on production environments).

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need to use exception. It allows doing what you want if your code does some unexpected happened.

In the example below, you can see how it could work

```
try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

[Exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) See the documentation for more